# How to conveniently handle long lists of parameters in C++ class templates?

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to ask about guidelines on **how to ellegantly use long parameters lists in class templates**. The inconviency is that you need to repeat the parameter list twice when defining (templated) methods, consts etc. in the templated class.

The question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676638/template-method-pattern-and-long-parameter-lists-in-c), but no example code is provided and I still fail to compile most of my attempts. Usually nothing is gained when I move the parameters somewhere else as I only have to define my long list of parameters in another place(constructor, struct etc.).

I will try to give an MWE. I want to achieve something like:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class MyInt_t, int _N, int _M, MyInt_t _A, MyInt_t _B> class MyClass{
// generally this list is even longer and composed of fundamental classes
// and MyInt_t template type-parameter
  public:
   static const int N = _N, M = _M; // any way not to keep different names
                                    // for params and fields? N = MyPars.N?
   // static const MyInt_t MA[2] = {_A, _B}; // ...but ofc it will not work
   // also cannot (or do not know how to) pass arrays to templates
   static const MyInt_t MA[2];      // another repetition of template parameters below
   MyInt_t getSth();
   // rest of implementation with non-static fields and methods
};

// static const array definition
template <class MyInt_t, int _N, int _M, MyInt_t _A, MyInt_t _B>
         const MyInt_t MyClass<MyInt_t, _N, _M, _A, _B>::MA[2] = {_A,_B};

// and now to defining the method...
template <class MyInt_t, int _N, int _M, MyInt_t _A, MyInt_t _B>
  MyInt_t MyClass<MyInt_t, _N, _M, _A, _B>::getSth(){
    std::cout << "Yey! " << N << ", " << M << " || " << MA[1] << std::endl;
    return MA[0];
  }

typedef MyClass<long long unsigned, 5,6, ~123ull, -5ull> MySpecClass1;
typedef MyClass<long unsigned, 13,19, 123ull, 456ull>    MySpecClass2;

// main()
int main()
{
  MySpecClass1 Obj1;
  long long unsigned test = Obj1.getSth();
  std::cout << "Bye! " << test << " || " << MySpecClass2::N << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Yey! 5, 6 || 18446744073709551611
Bye! 18446744073709551492 || 13
```

**Note1:** I'm too shy to use preprocessor definitions, but when the list of parameteres has more than ten constant parameters which I notoriously have to repeat then it becomes IMHO not readable. Whereas the purpose of templates is a clean way to utilize your code many times... So I must be doing sth wrong... There is also the problem of having two different names for one parameter: the names of the field and the template non-type constant have to be different.

**Note2:** I want those to be static constants because they will characterise the whole specialised class and not the instance of it. I also like const because of compiler optimisation.

**Summary:** I feel the code above is not ellegant and has a tendency to grow a lot uglier when the list of constants is elongating. There is a lot of mathematical algorythms (like random number generators, solvers) that take a long list of static constants.

Comment: Let me also add that, say, there a two types involed, the "int" type, and the "MyInt_t" type. One could sort parameters in two groups (arrays, structs...), but arrays pose different problems in templates (pointers, lengths, references etc.), and as the "MyInt_t" type is unknown it needs to be templated... Just thinking loudly.